# passing asp.net class object in javascript in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am having the below code in my project

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Alerts.aspx/TestMethod",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnError
    });
```

now I want to pass the "this" or me(vb.net) as parameter in data object how to pass the current class object.

can any one help me

I tried  `data: "{obj:"<%=Me%>"}",`

but it is not working can anyone help ...

Comment: The only thing you'll be able to pass from VB to Javascript are literals - things like string, number, array/object in Javascript format. `Me` is a reference to a date type in VB and cannot be stored in Javascript.

Comment: but i heard like we can pass the custom class object in jquery.. do u have any idea regarding the same??

Comment: you will have to serialize Me and store it in a hidden element and then get that element when sending to server.

Comment: i am new to asp.net can any one give me a link to achieve the above one